# Summing Values from a Cursor for TextView

Tags: android, cursor

I am trying to sum values from two cursors and put the result into a text view. When the cursor is only returning one value it works perfect but when there is more then one value being returned and I have to put the cursors into a while loop it stops working.

What is meant to happen is the main cursor `ingredientsCursor` returns a list or ingredients (this is working), then inside the while loop two cursors take the results from the main cursor to carry out two separate queries, the results are then multiplied and added to a running total to be displayed.

When I run the code without the while loop knowing I am only going to get one result from `ingredientsCursor` everything works fine, its when there is more then one result and I have to use the while loop. I have set the total to be a global variable thinking that was part if the problem but still just getting the blank space.

**Working Display with on result (no While loop)**

```
        final Cursor ingredientsCursor = adapter.getRecipesIngredients(recipeCode);
        ingredientsCursor.moveToFirst();

        String name = ingredientsCursor.getString(ingredientsCursor.getColumnIndex("ingredient_name"));

        final Cursor c = adapter.getRecipeCalories(name);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int cal = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("calories"));

        final Cursor m = adapter.getMeasurement(recipeCode, name);
        m.moveToFirst();
        int meas = m.getInt(m.getColumnIndex("measurement"));

        int total = cal * meas;

        recipeCalories.setText("Calories:" + total);
```

**With While loop, displaying blank**

```
    final Cursor ingredientsCursor = adapter.getRecipesIngredients(recipeCode);
    ingredientsCursor.moveToFirst();
    while(ingredientsCursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = ingredientsCursor.getString(ingredientsCursor.getColumnIndex("ingredient_name"));

        final Cursor c = adapter.getRecipeCalories(name);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int cal = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("calories"));

        final Cursor m = adapter.getMeasurement(recipeCode, name);
        m.moveToFirst();
        int meas = m.getInt(m.getColumnIndex("measurement"));

        int MainActivity.total = cal * meas;

    }

    recipeCalories.setText("Calories:" + MainActivity.total);
```

Comment: add while loop and update cal and meas value every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the total value on each cycle step.

```
  final Cursor ingredientsCursor = adapter.getRecipesIngredients(recipeCode);
    ingredientsCursor.moveToFirst();
    while(ingredientsCursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = ingredientsCursor.getString(ingredientsCursor.getColumnIndex("ingredient_name"));

        final Cursor c = adapter.getRecipeCalories(name);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int cal = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("calories"));

        final Cursor m = adapter.getMeasurement(recipeCode, name);
        m.moveToFirst();
        int meas = m.getInt(m.getColumnIndex("measurement"));
        // here is your error
        int MainActivity.total = cal * meas;

    }
```

You need to change your code to :

```
   final Cursor ingredientsCursor = adapter.getRecipesIngredients(recipeCode);
    ingredientsCursor.moveToFirst();
    int sum = 0;
    while(ingredientsCursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = ingredientsCursor.getString(ingredientsCursor.getColumnIndex("ingredient_name"));

        final Cursor c = adapter.getRecipeCalories(name);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int cal = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("calories"));

        final Cursor m = adapter.getMeasurement(recipeCode, name);
        m.moveToFirst();
        int meas = m.getInt(m.getColumnIndex("measurement"));

        sum += (cal * meas);

    }

    recipeCalories.setText("Calories:" + sum);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, its gotten rid of the blank space but now I am just getting a 0

Comment: @JJSmith are you sure that you have a right values on `cal` and `meas`? Maybe one of this is `0`. Becuase in this case it will be simple math : `x * 0 = 0`. And this can be produce `0` result.

Comment: Yea I am positive that the values are right because taking your code above and removing the while loop it works fine, the while loop seems to be doing something to mess with it

Comment: on further looking at the actual app it does actually work, if there is more then one value being returned to the name string it works fine but if there is only one it does work, a slight bug but something that wont really effect the overall app, thanks again for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Everytime the while loop runs you are overwriting int MainActivity.total.
Try putting all the total values in a list of values and showing data from there.